# Share Keychain between app and keyboard in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, keychain

I am trying to share the Keychain between an app and a keyboard extension, but i receive the following error when i try to access the keychain from the keyboard:

```
OSStatus error:[-25291] No keychain is available. You may need to restart your computer.
```

Though, I can access the Keychain from the app without any issues.

I have turned on the Keychain Sharing for both the app and the extension. App Groups is also turned on for both.

Entitlements.plist for the app:
[image]

Entitlements.plist for the extension:
[image]

Info.plist for the extension:
[image]

This is how I am accessing the keychain (I am using KeychainAccess library) in both app and extension (ABCD1234 -> Represents the Team ID):

```
let keychain = Keychain(service: "group.com.company.app", accessGroup: "ABCD1234.group.com.company.app")
```

I have also turned on the "Full Keyboard Access" on my phone, but its still not working.

Is there anything I am missing?

p.s. it seems to be working good on the Simulator, but not when i run it on a real device through Xcode or through TestFlight.